# Random Error 824 - All Environments

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, errors, corruption

We have been experiencing seemingly random error 824 on our DEV/QA/PROD SQL 2017 Enterprise servers.  The servers run nearly identical code ingesting identical daily files via an ETL process into our data warehouse.  The errors were first noticed around May 2022, but due to log cleanups, we can't be sure as the (vendor supplied) ETL process is catching these errors, logging a warning and continues processing instead of failing!

DEV/QA have been patched to CU30 (latest CU) -- the condition still exists.
Production is a few patches behind at CU22, and is scheduled to be patched in the coming weeks.

Example:

> SQL Server detected a logical inconsistency-based I/O error: incorrect
> checksum (expected 0xc30164e7; actual 0x9f2bc675c).  It occurred
> during a read of page (7:1306400) in database ID 2 at offset
> 0x0000027de40000 in file 'H:\tempdb_mssql_6.ndf'.

As stated, this is happening randomly on all of our environments.  All servers are virtualized.
DEV/QA are both utilizing the same SAN.  Production is on a separate SAN in a different data centre.  I do not have details on make/model of the SAN devices.

For the most part, when this happens, it seems to mostly be in tempdb (but, not always).  Also, suspect_pages is more often than not, empty.  It also appears to happen more often on Saturdays as we had it happen 3-4 in a row.

Also noted, is that the expected/actual values listed in the error, are often the same -- but not always.

It has also been noted that a particular stored procedure seems to be more susceptible to this error being thrown, but, it has happened at multiple other places in the ETL job, again impacting different databases.  The stored procedure that seems to trigger this error most often adds a PERSISTED computed column, then a ROW_NUMBER() based on that computed column -- to 5 tables, ranging from 200K to 7.5M rows in size.  We modified this procedure yesterday (in QA) to limit the number of rows updated with the ROW_NUMBER() value (only where rownum=1) and changed that update from an all at once, to a 25K batched approach.  The error happened again today in QA -- so we removed the PERSISTED option on the computed column.  We are literally trying anything to stop this in QA as it seems most impacted.

DBCC CHECKDB is run on all production databases, except one, daily.  The one skipped database is quite large at just shy of 4TB and DBCC CHECKDB takes about 12 hours to complete.  DBCC CHECKDB has been run on a recent production backup in QA on this large database, and it was clean.

As of yet, only tempdb has been affected on production.  DEV/QA have seen a couple other databases impacted, yet DBCC CHECKDB yields nothing, even when suspect_pages contains an entry.  We have restored the production database to DEV/QA when its not tempdb, just to be safe.

When tempdb is impacted, we have been stopping SQL, and deleting the offending tempdb file and restarting the service.

It's worth noting that H: is at 100% usage in production as the mdf/ndf files consume the entire 150GB drive, but there is ample free space within the files.  DEV/QA are not at 100%, and have about 30-40GB free space, and both show tempdb being impacted.  So I don't think its a drive space issue.

I have contacted our DBA, who believes the issue is being caused by the data itself.  While I do not agree the data is at fault, we did upgrade the system that generates the CSV files being read by the ETL job in April 2022.  The source system is now linux based rather than windows based.  The ETL process required no changes to read the new files.  The data within the files changed in structure a bit, but they were largely identical, and the CLR procs can adapt to structural changes based on a schema layout file that is sent daily.  The files are sufficiently large (55+GB a day) that they populate over 300 tables each consisting of a vast amount of nvarchar(max) fields.

I have contacted our infrastructure team to check VM/SAN health -- and while production's VM has reports of high IO during the file ingestion phase (time stamps line up perfectly) - there are no errors reported.  Our infrastructure team during their investigations migrated the prod VM to a faster host, and the files moved to a new relatively unused newer SAN.

On July 26th the DEV/QA SAN suffered a drive failure which resulted in two drives being replaced and rebuilt.  Since the drive failure, we went without an incident as we worked with Microsoft, however this past Saturday, and this past Monday - QA had more errors related to tempdb.

We have opened a ticket with Microsoft, and after several weeks/calls, we have been told they were the wrong team (they only help fix corruption) and we needed a premier ticket.  So we are at present, asking for a quote from Microsoft for a premier ticket to aid in root cause analysis.

In the meantime, I'm hoping production doesn't have further issues, and I'm hoping someone might be able to offer some further insights or guidance on what we can do to analyze this issue, or limit its occurrence until we can get Microsoft properly engaged.

**Edit 1a - Full @@VERSION output**

```
DEV: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU30) (KB5013756) - 14.0.3451.2 (X64)   Jun 22 2022 18:20:15   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor) 
QA: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU30) (KB5013756) - 14.0.3451.2 (X64)   Jun 22 2022 18:20:15   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor) 
PROD: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU22-GDR) (KB4583457) - 14.0.3370.1 (X64)   Nov  6 2020 18:19:52   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

**Edit 1b - Suspect Procedure**
*Failure occurs in code following comment: BATCH UPDATE RN - CURRENT/PAST ROWS*

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @schema SYSNAME, @table SYSNAME, @RNCurrDepth SMALLINT, @RNFutureDepth SMALLINT, @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE IDComp3 CURSOR LOCAL
    FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT S.name, T.name, P.RNCurrentDescDepth, P.RNFutureAscDepth
    FROM sys.columns C
    JOIN sys.tables T ON C.object_id=T.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas S ON T.schema_id=S.schema_id
    JOIN dbo.ParseIDComp3Control P ON S.name=P.TableSchema AND T.name=TableName /* Control Table to limit the tables parsed, and how many ROW_NUMBERS to update */
    WHERE C.name='ID_COMP_3'
    AND P.Active=1
    ORDER BY T.name;
    OPEN IDComp3;
    FETCH NEXT FROM IDComp3 INTO @schema, @table, @RNCurrDepth, @RNFutureDepth;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        --RAISERROR(@TABLE,0,1) WITH NOWAIT;

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TMP;
        CREATE TABLE #TMP ([@ID] NVARCHAR(150)
                          ,LEAD_CO_MNE NVARCHAR(50)
                          ,RNCURRENTDESC INT
                          ,RNFUTUREASC INT);

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TMP_BATCH;
        CREATE TABLE #TMP_BATCH ([@ID] NVARCHAR(150)
                                ,LEAD_CO_MNE NVARCHAR(50)
                                ,RNCURRENTDESC INT
                                ,RNFUTUREASC INT);

        /* DROP ID_COMP_3 COLUMNS IF EXISTS, TO ENSURE WE HAVE NO VALUES */
        SET @SQL='';
        SELECT @SQL+='ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(S.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(T.name)+' DROP COLUMN '+QUOTENAME(C.name)+';'+CHAR(10)
            FROM sys.columns C
            JOIN sys.tables T ON C.object_id=T.object_id
            JOIN sys.schemas S ON T.schema_id=S.schema_id
            WHERE C.name IN ('ID_COMP_3_DATE','ID_COMP_3_ID')
            AND S.name=@schema
            AND T.name=@table
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;

        /* ADD COMPUTED COLUMNS IF NOT EXISTS */
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM sys.columns C
                        JOIN sys.tables T ON C.object_id=T.object_id
                        JOIN sys.schemas S ON T.schema_id=S.schema_id
                        WHERE C.name='ID_COMP_3_DATE'
                        AND S.name=@schema
                        AND T.name=@table)
        BEGIN   
            SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(@schema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@table)+'ADD ID_COMP_3_DATE AS TRY_CONVERT(DATE,LEFT(ID_COMP_3,8),112),
                                                                                    ID_COMP_3_ID AS TRY_CONVERT(INT,RIGHT(ID_COMP_3,LEN(ID_COMP_3)-CHARINDEX(''.'',ID_COMP_3)));'
            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
        END

        /* DROP INDEXES IF EXISTS (SO WE CAN DROP COLUMNS) */
        SET @SQL='';
        SELECT @SQL+='DROP INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(I.name) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(S.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(T.name)+CHAR(10)
            FROM sys.indexes I
            JOIN sys.tables T ON I.object_id=T.object_id
            JOIN sys.schemas S ON T.schema_id=S.schema_id
            WHERE T.name=@table
            AND S.name=@schema
            AND I.name IN ('IX_'+t.name+'_RN_Current_Desc', 'IX_'+t.name+'_RN_Future_Asc')
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;

        /* DROP RN COLUMNS IF EXISTS, TO ENSURE WE HAVE NO VALUES */
        SET @SQL='';
        SELECT @SQL+='ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(S.name)+'.'+QUOTENAME(T.name)+' DROP COLUMN '+QUOTENAME(C.name)+';'+CHAR(10)
            FROM sys.columns C
            JOIN sys.tables T ON C.object_id=T.object_id
            JOIN sys.schemas S ON T.schema_id=S.schema_id
            WHERE C.name IN ('RN_Current_Desc','RN_Future_Asc')
            AND S.name=@schema
            AND T.name=@table
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;

        /* ADD RN COLUMNS */
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM sys.columns C
                        JOIN sys.tables T ON C.object_id=T.object_id
                        JOIN sys.schemas S ON T.schema_id=S.schema_id
                        WHERE C.name='RN_Current_Desc'
                        AND S.name=@schema
                        AND T.name=@table)
        BEGIN   
            SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(@schema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@table)+'ADD RN_Current_Desc SMALLINT,
                                                                                    RN_Future_Asc SMALLINT;'
            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
        END

        /* ADD INDEX TO @ID/RNS */
        SET @SQL = 'CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_'+@table+'_RN_Current_Desc] ON '+QUOTENAME(@schema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@table)+' ([@ID], LEAD_CO_MNE, RN_Current_Desc ASC) WHERE (RN_Current_Desc <= '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),@RNCurrDepth)+');
                    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_'+@table+'_RN_Future_Asc] ON '+QUOTENAME(@schema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@table)+' ([@ID], LEAD_CO_MNE, RN_Future_Asc DESC)  WHERE (RN_Current_Desc <= '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),@RNFutureDepth)+');
                    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TMP_Current_Desc] ON #TMP ([@ID], LEAD_CO_MNE) INCLUDE(RNCURRENTDESC, RNFUTUREASC);
                    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TMPBATCH_Current_Desc] ON #TMP_BATCH ([@ID], LEAD_CO_MNE) INCLUDE(RNCURRENTDESC, RNFUTUREASC);';
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;

        /* BATCH UPDATE RN - CURRENT/PAST ROWS */
        SET @SQL = ';WITH X AS
                    (
                    SELECT [@ID]
                          ,LEAD_CO_MNE
                          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID_COMP_1, LEAD_CO_MNE ORDER BY ID_COMP_3_DATE DESC, ID_COMP_3_ID DESC) AS RNCURRENTDESC
                    FROM '+QUOTENAME(@schema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@table)+'
                    WHERE ID_COMP_3_DATE <= MIS_DATE
                    )
                    INSERT INTO #TMP ([@ID],LEAD_CO_MNE,RNCURRENTDESC)
                    SELECT [@ID], LEAD_CO_MNE, RNCURRENTDESC
                    FROM X
                    WHERE RNCURRENTDESC <= @RNCurrDepth;
                    
                    DECLARE @BATCH INT = 25000;
                    WHILE @BATCH > 0
                    BEGIN
                        UPDATE TOP(@BATCH) X
                        SET RN_Current_Desc = T.RNCURRENTDESC
                        FROM '+QUOTENAME(@schema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@table)+' X
                        JOIN #TMP T ON X.[@ID]=T.[@ID] AND X.LEAD_CO_MNE=T.LEAD_CO_MNE
                        WHERE X.RN_Current_Desc IS NULL;

                        SET @BATCH=@@ROWCOUNT;
                    END'
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@RNCurrDepth SMALLINT', @RNCurrDepth=@RNCurrDepth;

        TRUNCATE TABLE #TMP;

        /* RN - FUTURE ROWS */
        SET @SQL = ';WITH X AS
                    (
                    SELECT [@ID]
                          ,LEAD_CO_MNE
                          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID_COMP_1, LEAD_CO_MNE ORDER BY ID_COMP_3_DATE ASC, ID_COMP_3_ID DESC) AS RNFUTUREASC
                    FROM '+QUOTENAME(@schema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@table)+'
                    WHERE ID_COMP_3_DATE > MIS_DATE
                    )
                    INSERT INTO #TMP ([@ID],LEAD_CO_MNE,RNFUTUREASC)
                    SELECT [@ID],LEAD_CO_MNE,RNFUTUREASC
                    FROM X
                    WHERE RNFUTUREASC <= @RNFutureDepth

                    DECLARE @BATCH INT = 25000;
                    WHILE @BATCH > 0
                    BEGIN
                        UPDATE TOP(@BATCH) X
                        SET RN_Future_Asc = T.RNFUTUREASC
                        FROM '+QUOTENAME(@schema)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@table)+' X
                        JOIN #TMP T ON X.[@ID]=T.[@ID] AND X.LEAD_CO_MNE=T.LEAD_CO_MNE
                        WHERE X.RN_Future_Asc IS NULL;

                        SET @BATCH=@@ROWCOUNT;
                    END'
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@RNFutureDepth SMALLINT', @RNFutureDepth=@RNFutureDepth;

        FETCH NEXT FROM IDComp3 INTO @schema, @table, @RNCurrDepth, @RNFutureDepth;
    END
    CLOSE IDComp3
    DEALLOCATE IDComp3
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE(), 
            @Severity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY(), 
            @State SMALLINT =ERROR_STATE()
    RAISERROR(@Message, @Severity, @State);
    RETURN(1);
END CATCH
    
RETURN(0)
```

**Edit 1c - Sample Table Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ABC123
(
    [LEAD_CO_MNE] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BRANCH_CO_MNE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MIS_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [@ID] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ACTIVITY] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ACTION] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CHANGE_DATE_TYPE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CHANGE_PERIOD] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [CHANGE_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [CHANGE_ACTIVITY] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [PRIOR_DAYS] [int] NULL,
    [CHG_TO_PRODUCT] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ALLOWED_PRODUCT] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [RESERVED_6] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [RESERVED_5] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [INITIATION_TYPE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DEFAULT_ACTIVITY] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [RESERVED_4] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [RESERVED_3] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [RESERVED_2] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [RESERVED_1] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [LOCAL_REF] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PR_ATTRIBUTE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PR_VALUE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PR_BRK_RES] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PR_BRK_MSG] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PR_BRK_CHARGE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PR_RESERVED_3] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PR_RESERVED_2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PR_RESERVED_1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PR_APP_METHOD] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PR_APP_PERIOD] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SYS_RESERVE7] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [SYS_RESERVE6] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [SYS_RESERVE5] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [SYS_RESERVE4] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [SYS_RESERVE3] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [SYS_RESERVE2] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [SYS_RESERVE1] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [DEFAULT_ATTR_OPTION] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [DEFAULT_NEGOTIABLE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [NR_ATTRIBUTE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NR_OPTIONS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NR_RESERVED2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NR_RESERVED1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NR_STD_COMP] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NR_TYPE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NR_VALUE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NR_MESSAGE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CHANGED_FIELDS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NEGOTIATED_FLDS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ID_COMP_1] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ID_COMP_2] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ID_COMP_3] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ID_COMP_4] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ID_COMP_5] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ID_COMP_6] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [RESERVED2_ID] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [TARGET_PRODUCT] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [STMT_NOS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [OVERRIDE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [RECORD_STATUS] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CURR_NO] [int] NULL,
    [INPUTTER] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DATE_TIME] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [AUTHORISER] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [CO_CODE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [DEPT_CODE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AUDITOR_CODE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AUDIT_DATE_TIME] [int] NULL,
    [ARRANGEMENT_KEY] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [ETL_DQ_RevisionCount] [int] NULL,
    [ETL_DQ_ColumnsRevised] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [ETL_DQ_ErrorMessage] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [ETL_CHANGE_PERIOD] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [API_ATTRIBUTE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NR_ATTRIBUTE_RULE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NR_VALUE_SOURCE] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [OWNING_COMPANY] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ID_COMP_3_DATE]  AS (TRY_CONVERT([date],left([ID_COMP_3],(8)),(112))),
    [ID_COMP_3_ID]  AS (TRY_CAST(right([ID_COMP_3],len([ID_COMP_3])-charindex('.',[ID_COMP_3])) AS [int])),
    [RN_Current_Desc] [smallint] NULL,
    [RN_Future_Asc] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ABC123] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [@ID] ASC,
    [LEAD_CO_MNE] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: The errors occur during ETL processing, not during CHECKDB.  No errors return running CHECKDB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/vmware-sql-server-823-824-alerts ? Not sure if you’re running on VMWare and which version, but there is a known issue with VMware vSphere 7.0 Update 2 which sounds exactly like what you’re experiencing.

Comment: Confirming this was exactly the issue we have and we will be patching all servers in the coming days.  v7 update 3f contained a patch for this that disables the bloom filter.

Answer (score 7):

82x errors are rarely, if ever, a SQL Server issue as these are all error codes on something that doesn't make sense or has errored when returning to SQL Server code. For example, with 824 this can be caused by a bad driver or caching layer below SQL (including hardware and software such as the hypervisor, SAN, disk controller, etc.).

There are a few things to try to narrow down the issue:

1. Run [SQLIOSIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/tools/sqliosim-utility-simulate-activity-disk-subsystem) to see if any errors occur. If they do, it's not SQL Server.
2. Check for known issues for your hypervisor - such as [VMWare drivers](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/88201?lang=en_US) which cause 823/824 errors and make appropriate configuration changes.
3. Take and look at a storport trace to see if there are other issues that might be helping to cause the problem during the time period and the data returned.